# Stored procedure performance - this is WILD?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This question is not so much about finding a solution as about getting an explanation for the **bizarrest** behavior I have ever seen from SQL Server.

I had a stored procedure with the following signature:

```
alter procedure MySP @param1 uniqueidentifier, 
                     @param2 uniqueidentifier, 
                     @param3 uniqueidentifier
```

Given a certain set of parameters, this proc was taking a very long time to run from C# (using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`) - about 2 minutes.  Using the same parameters in a direct query session, the SP ran in under 2 seconds.

It took a long time, and I won't even try to explain how we stumbled upon this solution, but this is what we did:

At the beginning of the SP, we declared 3 local variables and assigned them to the values of the parameters, like so:

```
declare @param1_copy uniqueidentifier, 
        @param2_copy uniqueidentifier, 
        @param3_copy uniqueidentifier

select @param1_copy = @param1,
       @param2_copy = @param2,
       @param3_copy = @param3
```

And then, in the rest of the SP we substituted all references to the input parameters with the local copies.

Voila.  SP executed in under 2 seconds.  And the team here is gobsmacked.

Now, ladies and gentlemen, can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [parameter sniffing](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/17/sql-parameter-sniffing-and-what-to-do-about-it/).

From Microsoft's definition:

> "Parameter sniffing" refers to a process whereby SQL Server's execution environment "sniffs" the current parameter values during compilation or recompilation, and passes it along to the query optimizer so that they can be used to generate potentially faster query execution plans. The word "current" refers to the parameter values present in the statement call that caused a compilation or a recompilation.

Looks like you've already figured out one fix, another would be to use EXEC... WITH RECOMPILE:

> When executing a stored procedure with atypical parameter values, "EXEC ... WITH RECOMPILE" can be used to ensure that the fresh query plan does not replace an existing cached plan that was compiled using typical parameter values.

Comment: Amazing.  We stumbled on the textbook solution without realizing!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading the excellent article by Erland Sommarskog: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

It has full details on this issue.

In general, when a query plan is cached, some of the query settings are used in the cache key. These settings are different in the default SSMS settings than they would be on a default connection strings, so different query plans may exist.

Comment: Probably best using a different word than `parameter` here to avoid confusion with stored procedure parameters.

Comment: @MartinSmith - fair point. Changed to `settings` - what do you think?

Comment: Seems good to me. The DMO these can be found in is `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`

Comment: @Shaul - I suggest looking at his other articles. The dynamic SQL one is a cracker as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when I had a parameter of type xml and was taking lots of time to execute. I did the same approach and created a local variable and passed the parameter value in and it worked super fast :)

When SQL starts compiling the SP to create its execution plan, it takes into account the values passed in its parameters to influence the execution plan. But if you assign the parameter values to a local variable and use that variable throughout your SP code, then the SQL won't take the parameters into account to influence the execution plan, hence you get a faster response from the query.